# Angularjs object type to handle HTML contents which are in string variables

Tags: java, html, angularjs

From a WYSIWYG text editor I take comments from the users for a table representation in my web page. Those are stored in the database as Varchar. When I take back them to the front end to render again in a separate view, I use `ng-bind-html` directive to convert this string to HTML. I need to edit them before display. What is the suitable Angularjs object type for this? It should be capable to handle this string as HTML tags.

One of my string type html content is looks like:

`<p> Table name:sc_0.25 </ p> <p> Grading:Good </ p> <p> Content:Ok </ p>`

Comment: Are you sure this is about Angular? As far as I know `ng-bind-html` only exists in AngularJS. Please change the `angular` tag to `angularjs` to make it clear what Angular your question is about.

Comment: Yes it is Angularjs. Changed it